# How to disable Checkbox unless one checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, haml

i have two check boxes, when one check box is clicked then the other one must be enable otherwise it should be disabled (both check box and text)

HAML code:

```
  %label.checkbox
      = check_box_tag 'Name'
      Name
    %label.checkbox
      = check_box_tag 'Description'
      Description
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a little jQuery:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="enabler" />
<input type="checkbox" class="optional" disabled />
<input type="checkbox" class="optional" disabled />
```

JS:

```
$(".enabler").on("change", function(e) {
    $(".optional").prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G7pst/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="func();" />
<input type="checkbox" id="dis"  disabled="disable" />
```

JQuery

```
    function func(){
    var optObj = $("checkbox#dis");
     if(optObj.attr("disabled"))
     optObj.removeAttr("disabled");
     else
     optObj.attr("disabled", "disable");
}
```

Comment: second check box is still disable when click first checkbox i want enable